# Where do Docker containers created in Google Cloud Shell go?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform

I created a new project in Cloud Console, visited Marketplace and ran a pull command in Cloud Shell (as suggested: copy/paste) which worked fine and logged everything as expected. No errors or warnings.

Now I can't find any containers anywhere. Where did the containers go?

I assume something like Write-Only-Memory does not exist, so I clearly missed something.

Comment: The container is in your Cloud Shell environment. Perform a `docker image ls` to list your images. Then you can push them to artifact registry, or elsewhere. As any Docker client!

Comment: Ok, so Cloud Shell is just a disposable VM that's not listed anywhere else?

Comment: Can you check this [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/how-cloud-shell-works).

Comment: Yes, Cloud Shell is a micro VM, available for free, with a shared CPU and only 5Gb of storage. Just for testing, experimentation, or quick API calls. It's not listed in your project because the VM lives in a Google project, not yours. Cloud Shell is not connected to your VPC!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The container is in your Cloud Shell environment, as indicated in the comments section by @guillaume blaquiere. According to the [Documentation-1](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_ls/), you can list them by using the command `Docker image ls`. For information on pushing and pulling images to the artifact registry, check the [Documentation-2](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/docker/store-docker-container-images).

And for your second question

> so Cloud Shell is just a disposable VM that's not listed anywhere else?

You can check with the document [How cloud shell works](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/how-cloud-shell-works) which clearly explains,

> Cloud Shell provisions a Compute Engine virtual machine running a Debian->based Linux operating system for your temporary use. This virtual machine is >owned and managed by Google Cloud, so will not appear within any of your GCP >projects.
>
> Cloud Shell instances are provisioned on a per-user, per-session basis. The >instance persists while your Cloud Shell session is active; after an hour of >inactivity, your session terminates and its VM is discarded. For more on >usage quotas, refer to the [limitations guide](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/limitations#usage_limits).

Comment: Thanks. I was somewhat in panic I might have inadvertently broken something or comprimised security (or both). I expected the shell to be just some kind of command prompt. Entering commands into a shell that is NOT owned by us is actually a No Go. I'm glad this was just an experiment.